# can't pass json data directly to codemirror in vue3

Tags: vuejs3, codemirror

I am working with vue-codemirror in vue3, the version is

```
"@codemirror/lang-javascript": "^6.2.1",
"@codemirror/lang-json": "^6.0.1",
"codemirror": "^6.0.1",
"vue-codemirror": "^6.1.1"
```

I want to pass a json data object to codeminrror as showed in the code below.

```
 <codemirror v-model="data" :options="emOption" placeholder="Code gose here..." :style="{ height: '100%' }" :autofocus="true" :tabSize="5" :extensions="extensions" />

const data = ref({'name':'adfadf','age':23});
const  emOption = ref({
    mode: 'application/json',
        lineNumbers: true,
        tabSize: 2,
        autofocus: true,
});
const extensions = [json()];
```

but running the code comes with an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (config.doc || "").split is not a function
```

I know another way to get around is to use JSON.stringify(data), but that is getting things complicated for me, what I want to do is to show the JSON data directly in codemirror direclty without transforming.

Comment: The v-model of codemirror only accepts strings.  It's a fancy text editor, so it doesn't accept _actual_ code.  Your `data` variable must be a string.  You don't have to stringify it necessarily, but just wrap the code with quotations: `const data = ref("{ name: 'adfadf', age: 23 }")` should work perfectly fine.